# Facebook Graph, how i can retrive info like lenght for a shared video?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

This is the flow i'm trying to create:

i see a public video on facebook and i take the link -> i close facebook ios app -> open my ios app -> paste the link in a textfield -> share the link on my facebook timeline after a login.

The code i use to share the link is:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [params setObject:@"https://www.facebook.com/facebookuser/videos/23948249872938/" forKey:@"link"];
 [params setObject:[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString] forKey:@"access_token"];

  FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                parameters:params
                                HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {

      // Handle the result
      if (!error) {



      }
      else{
          NSLog(@"error %@",error.description);
      }

  }];
```

All works correctly, the trouble comes if i try to retrive some information about the video, like the lenght. I have tried to test a call in Facebook Graph Tool to retrive lenght, i have tried:

```
GET /v2.6/{video-id} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

and i have add the length field. Result is this error:

```
"error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (length) on node type (Post)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "xxxxx"
  }
```

Why? Maybe my share isn't view as a video but only as a post? How i can retrive the lenght of this shared video?

Comment: Maybe the field is called length

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself, the id returned it's a post id, not a video id. In Graph Api length of an attached post video is in "properties" node.